# Redirect to Login.cshtml MVC 5 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made an custom authorize in my `HomeController`. 
I have this :

```
[CustomAuthorize]
ActionResult Planning()
```

When the user is connected, he can reach a specific page. I made URL for this. But if the user is not connected, I want to redirect him to the Login page but I had an url error with `"~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml"`.

Thanks in advance !

**Edit my code :**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null
            && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("student"))
            {
                var result = new ViewResult();
                result.ViewData.Model = "Home";
                result.ViewName = "~/Views/Roles/Student.cshtml";
                result.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
                filterContext.Result = result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            here the redirection to the Account/Login page
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your `CustomAuthorize` attribute...

Comment: My code is present now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");//Your path goes here
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
```

Try to return true/false from the OnAuthorize, this would hit the handler on return false. This is a better approach.
Try out with this. This default Handler comes into action when an authorization fails.
Hope this works our.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use filter context something this

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/home/login");
```